# subclassing MKAnnotation error, conform to Protocol

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation

I've looked at other codes and snippets from other stack overflow questions on subclassing. All I'm trying to do is subclass MKAnnotation. I'm using Xcode 6.3. This code works on my friend's but not mine.

I get a ***Type 'Annotation' does not conform to protocol 'MKAnnotation'*** error

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import UIKit

class Annotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String

   init(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String) {
      self.location = location
      self.title = title
      self.subtitle = subtitle
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not fully conforming to the `MKAnnotation` protocol. In addition to the `title` & `subtitle` properties (which are actually optional), you need to expose a `coordinate` property (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/)).

Your `location` (which is a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`) will do the trick if you simply rename it.